Tavern pytest debugging
is there a way to add a debug trace to purest tavern test from the file mymodule.tavern.yaml?
We use mock and unittest mock libraries and I am struggling to debug my tests. Is there a way I can add a import pdb.set_trace() to the yaml?
---
test_name: test_import_from_azure_storage
strict: false
marks:
- usefixtures:
  - django_live_url
  - fflag_fix_all_lsdv_4711_cors_errors_accessing_task_data_short_off
stages:
- id: signup
  type: ref

